# Area of the quadrilateral within a triangle

Tags: geometry

Given the area of tringles $BEF=X,BFC=Y$ and $FDC=Z$, Can we find the area of the quadrilateral $AEFD$ in terms of $X,Y,Z$?
[image]

Comment: Which three : $$BEF, BFC, CDF$$ or $ABC$ and other two?

Comment: No, we know nothing but the area of the given triangles.

Comment: @Mathslover Where did you get this problem from?

Comment: @metacompactness myself (:

Comment: @Mathslover How do you know that the solution is unique?

Comment: @metacompactness I dunno, thats why I posted it here.....

Comment: @rschwieb Tried doing this but this is getting really ugly :(

Comment: @Mathslover Answers are not guaranteed to be short and neat...

Answer (score 0):

Let $U = AEF$ and $V = ADF$. Note that $AEFD = U + V$.

$BCE\frac{AB}{BE} = ABC \Rightarrow (X+Y)\frac{AB}{BE} = X + Y + Z + U + V$

$BEF\frac{AB}{BE} = ABF \Rightarrow X\frac{AB}{BE} = X + U$

Dividing this two equations we get:

$\frac{X+Y}{X} = \frac{X + Y + Z + U + V}{X + U} \Rightarrow (X + U)\frac{X+Y}{X} = X + Y + Z + U + V \Rightarrow X + Y + U + U\frac{Y}{X} = X + Y + U + V \Rightarrow \boxed{U\frac{Y}{X} = Z + V}$

Similarly:

$BCD\frac{AC}{CD} = ABC \Rightarrow (Y + Z)\frac{AC}{CD} = X + Y + Z + U + V$

$CDF\frac{AC}{CD} = ACF \Rightarrow Z\frac{AC}{CD} = Z + V$

Dividing this two equations we get:

$\frac{Y + Z}{Z} = \frac{X + Y + Z + U + V}{Z + V} \Rightarrow (Z + V)\frac{Y + Z}{Z} = X + Y+ Z + U + V \Rightarrow Y + Z + V + V\frac{Y}{Z} = X + Y + Z + U + V\Rightarrow \boxed{V\frac{Y}{Z} = X + U}$

We have a nice system of two equations with two unknowns $U$ and $V$.

This can be easily solved:

$$U = \frac{XYZ + X^2Z}{Y^2-XZ}$$

$$V = \frac{XYZ + XZ^2}{Y^2-XZ}$$

The area of the quadrilateral is $U + V$:

$$AEFD = U + V = \frac{2XYZ + X^2Z + XZ^2}{Y^2-XZ}$$

Comment: I think the two boxed results can be obtained directly by considering “the ratio of the areas of two triangles is the same ratio as their bases if the two triangles are of the same altitude.”

Comment: @Mick looks about right. I haven't thought of it. I haven't done classical geometry in ages and one tends to forget this stuff. LOL